# how to load external css file with lit

Tags: lit

Although lit provide some ways to deal with css, however I have some existing css files which I would like to use in some components, what should I do?

I have read this page https://lit.dev/docs/components/styles/ but now helpful with existing css files.

Comment: That guide includes a bit about loading external stylesheets using `link` and why that's not recommended https://lit.dev/docs/components/styles/#external-stylesheet

Answer (score 4):

Modern method: Only work with chromium based browser and safari.
Read more [Using CSS module scripts](https://web.dev/css-module-scripts/)

```
import styles from './my-styles.css' assert { type: 'css' }; 
class MyEl extends LitElement { 
     static styles = [styles];
}
```

Other solution:
By using vite build tools:

```
import style from "./style.css?inline";
class MyEl extends LitElement { 
   static styles = unsafeCSS(style);
}
```

Comment: When transpiling this with `tsc`, I get this error:

`error TS2307: Cannot find module './path/file.css' or its corresponding type declarations.` 

Any hints?

Comment: @JanDolejsi did you find any solution for this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Nope. If compiling using tsc into a CommonJS or ESM package is the goal, the only working solution I found was to paste the .css into the .ts file html template : (

But for a large 3rd party file, which would be insane to copy into the .ts component file, I decided to not use the shadow dom and leak the style from the main page into the component instead. All dirty.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is: Don't.

- The ShadyCSS polyfill doesn't support external style sheets.
- External styles can cause a flash-of-unstyled-content (FOUC) while they load.
- The URL in the href attribute is relative to the main document. This is okay if you're building an app and your asset URLs are well-known, but avoid using external style sheets when building a reusable element.

External css files should only be loaded in your html file (index.html most probably).

The css should be bundled with your element.
An alternative for reusabilty would be to export shared styles and import them in your styles properties as follows:

```
static styles: CSSResult[] = [
    // language=CSS
    AnimatedStyles,
    ShadowStyles,
    css`
[...]`;
```

And import from a shared file.

```
export const ShadowStyles = css`
[...]
`;
export const AnimatedStyles = css`
[...]
`;
```

That way, they are also loaded only once.

Answer (score 0):

for example I use PicoCSS with Lit JS cdn on static HTML file

**#1**
tag css file on static **index.html** file

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@picocss/pico@1/css/pico.min.css"
    />
  </head>
```

**#2**
and one inside Lit js elements, **app.js** file.

```
return html`
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@picocss/pico@1/css/pico.min.css"
  />
`;
```

**#3**
Next, copy any components from the PicoCSS framework's official site.

https://picocss.com/docs/accordions.html

*Here is my example below*

https://codesandbox.io/s/static-html-js-module-imports-forked-stxvuh?file=/app.js:1376-1386

It's not the best practice, but I found it worked.